# Como navegar com o react-router-dom quando ocorrer uma action

Tags: react, react-native, react-router

Olá, estou começando a trabalhar com React e estou fazendo uma integração com o Firebase. Meu problema é o seguinte, já consigo disparar todas as actions que preciso mas, quando eu disparo minha última ação de `USUARIO_ENTRAR_SUCESSO` eu preciso que o `react-router-dom` faça a navegação para a rota `/:uid`.

Meu reducer está assim:

```js
export const usuarioReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        // ...outras actions...
        case 'USUARIO_ENTRAR_SUCESSO': {
            // preciso navegar quando essa action for disparada
            return state;
        }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Como faço isso?

Comment: O Reducer jamais deve interagir dessa forma com a aplicação! Toda navegação deve ser feita através das actions, o Reducer apenas altera o estado.

Comment: significa então que, invés de eu chamar o reducer, eu posso simplesmente disparar uma ação?

Answer (score 1):

A navegação deve ser feita na própria action - o reducer apenas altera o estado da aplicação.

```
export const logar = ({
    email,
    senha
}) => {
    this.db.login(email, senha).then(res => {
        //faça a navegação por aqui
    }).catch(err => {
        //se der erro faça por aqui
    })
}
```

Comment: Entendi, nesse caso então como faço pra chamar o react-router-dom da ActionScript?

Comment: Infelizmente não sei trabalhar com react-router-dom pra navegação, portanto, não sei te responder nesse sentido. Eu utilizo o react-native-router-flux para navegar entre as páginas.

Comment: Vou ler sobre ele... Tem alguma referência aí

Comment: A própria documentação é mais do que necessário pra começar a usar ele, é bem simples de usar. [link](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/blob/master/docs/API.md)